# Delete files which has the same prefix

Tags: php, file, unlink

```
$prefix = 'something_prefix';
unlink($prefix.'.*');
```

the code above is not working, but I see some code like this below works just fine

```
unlink('*.jpg');
```

why? I am wonder is this going to work?

```
unlink('*.*');
```

how to delete the files which they begin with the same string? like this

```
same123.jpg
sametoo.png
samexxx.gif
```

they all begins with the string "same" but ends with different extension, how to do this?

I alread have a cheap way to do this, but I wonder if there is any better solution?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$mask = 'your_prefix_*.*';
array_map('unlink', glob($mask));
```

p.s. `glob()` requires PHP 4.3.0+

Comment: Hi Shivan, can you please clarify this for me?  Does this mean the problem is that `unlink()` accepts a file _name_, rather than a file _pattern_ (and hence `glob()` is required to find all file _names_ based on a _pattern_)?  That all makes sense, but then why did the OP's `unlink('*.jpg');` example work OK if patterns are not acceptable to `unlink()`?

Comment: `glob()` will list out all filenames based on the `$mask`. By `array_map()`, the `unlink` function will load once for each filenames listed by `glob()`.

Answer (score 32):

You can use [glob](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) for this. Something like this(didn't test it):

```
foreach (glob("something_prefix*.*") as $filename) {
    unlink($filename);
}
```

Comment: +1. I find this more readable than the `array_map` pattern suggested by @ShivanRaptor (and prefer not to use the functional `array_map` for imperative functions).

Comment: @catiel, Shivan Raptor's answer is shorter.

Comment: @sectus `short != better` :-)

Comment: @Sepster, it's subjective opinion in this case :^ ) I like callbacks.

Comment: @sectus I totally agree re subjective, and I _love_ callbacks ;-)  (Although _PHP_ callbacks kind of bug me as the callable is passed as a literal string and hence wide-open for run-time errors).

Comment: I prefer this. Because you can do much in loop.